# How to see the average milliseconds of functions by VS2022 Performance Profiler?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, profiling, benchmarking, cpu-usage

I use VS2022 [Performance Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/cpu-usage?view=vs-2022) to analysis my app.

I want to analyze the **average time in milliseconds of some hot path functions**. But Performance Profiler only show the total milliseconds and percentage.

Is it possible to show average milliseconds of specific function like [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/overview.html)?

Comment: That would require a profiler to know how many times a function had been called, which is not information it gets from just statistically sampling the program counter every so often.  That would require some kind of tracing, like hardware with Intel PT to have the CPU record conditional branch destinations. Or dynamic instrumentation like with Intel PIN.  Or static instrumentation like `gcc -O3 -pg` does, to create data for `gprof`.  But all of these have some overhead, so they're definitely not on by default.  `gcc -pg` is pretty lightweight.  I don't use VS, so IDK if it has any of these.

Comment: A microbenchmark that wraps a known repeat loop around a function creates a natural way to say something about average time for the way it was run in that experiment.  It might not be the average time "in the wild" when the caches and branch-history have some competition.